# How to combine reg expr matches together in one output?

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to combine in one output from grep these two separate results. What reg expression match should I use

```
grep "NS" file.txt 
 ftx.domainname.example.com  3600    IN    NS    ftxns01.domainname.example.com
```

```
grep "^sdfns[0-9]" file.txt 

ftxns001-oob.domainname.example.com. 86400 IN A    192.168.30.2
ftxns001.domainname.example.com.   86400 IN A    192.168.2.2
```

What can I include to exclude "-oob"

The desirable end effect for me would be:

```
ftx.domainname.example.com  3600    IN    NS    ftxns01.domainname.example.com
ftxns001.domainname.example.com.   86400 IN A    192.168.2.2
```

I figured just concatenating the first two results together would give me close results however I couldn't get excluding hostnames with "-oob" in the name to work when trying `grep [^oob]` or `[^-oob]`

Comment: I don't see how you're getting that second output. The regexp matches `sdfns` at the beginning of the line, but the output has `ftxns`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -v` to exclude lines that match a pattern.

```
grep "^sdfns[0-9]" file.txt | grep -v -e '-oob'
```

Or if you have GNU grep, you can use `-P` to get PCRE, and then use a negative lookahead.

```
grep '^sdfns\d+(?!-oob)' file.txt
```

`[^-oob]` doesn't work because that matches a single character that isn't in that list, it's not for excluding whole strings. It's the opposite of `[-oob]`, which matches a single character that *is* in that set.